# Tracking events in GTM when page redirects to payment system

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking, google-analytics-4

Who can help me, I got stuck. How can I track my thank you page with purchase event, when my website redirects customer to payment system , e.g. Stripe, then customer pays there. After this he is redirected to my website /thank you page. We have no Ecommerce , cos we are not online store.
When I try in GTM preview mode to make test purchase as a customer to see all event tracked, then in TAG Assistant summary no page follows (see attached , I have only main page the first and payment page where there are payment buttons) as I click on website outbound link to payment System and successfully purchase, although I thought  my /Thank you page will be seen there. Tag Assistant in preview mode just tells that it hasn't connected when thank you page opens.

Desired result is to have opportunity to track several purchase events with 3 values as we have 3 buttons on payment page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz1Gb.png)

Comment: Yes as @Sergej mentioned. If you checked there is already GTM snippet in the thanks you page. It might just some issue when preview mode. You can still install the right trigger and tag to test it on production environment. But be careful about if this will affect the real users checkout process.

Comment: I tried again as customer , When my payment succeeds and I am redirected to Thankyou page, then TagAssistant stops and tells Could not connect. When I push on it to Open in full window then It opens in second window and works. So I see it running as on payment page when I clicked button pay , as on my thankyou page. It seems like I have 2 session running simultaneously. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

- does thank you page has GTM script?
- debug thank you page instead w/o going all the process. If debugger does not load, check GTM / GA implementation. If debugger loads on thank you page, push script through Dev Tools Console.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have tried debug thankyou page w/o all the process, debugger loads and I see tags firing in GTM TAg Assistant on it. GTM snippet installed on thankyou page correctly. But how can I track successfull payment on Stripe with GTM? as I have redirect from my site payment page on Pay button -> then Stripe -> then Thank you page.  I can not control with tags and triggers what customer is doing on Stripe page. And when he successfully pays there , only then he is redirected to my Thankyou

Comment: Sadly you can not track the data on the stripe page. But you can see what's the data in your thanks you page. 
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page
Take this document as example. It looks like when the payment success, it will redirect to your success page. But it can contain the checkout session and it might have the order information you need for GA4.